# Диспетчер задач неправильно показывает загруженность CPU?

Tags: windows, железо, cpu

Имеется сервер kraftway isp es24 с двумя xeon e5405.
Поставил на него Win10. Сразу после установки диспетчер задач показывает 40% загруженности CPU. Это меня очень смутило.
Воспользовавшись другими программами, выяснил, что загрузка CPU ~2-4%.
Почему диспетчер задач показывает такие цифры? Кому стоит верить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какие процессы грузят ЦП с точки зрения диспетчера задач?

Comment: Вот как это выглядит сейчас!
http://joxi.ru/KAx9px7UMdP5Kr.jpg
Насколько я понимаю даже родной монитор ресурсов не видит что нагружает процессор. Хотя пишет загрузка 38%

Comment: В квантовой физике есть такое понятие, что сам факт измерения изменяет объект. У Вас похоже та же ситуация